I need help to evaluate without contour integratio :$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln(x)}{(x+a)(x+b)} dx$
I need help to evaluate :$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln(x)}{(x+a)(x+b)} dx$$
My idea :
$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln(x)}{(x+a)(x+b)} dx=\frac{1}{a-b}\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln(x)}{x+b}-\frac{\ln(x)}{x+a} dx$$
I thought about calculating the integral separately but this integral $\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln(x)}{x+a} dx$ does not converge
This proplem in book Table of Integrals, Series, and Products Eighth Edition page 540
The answer is presented in this book as:
$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln(x)}{(x+a)(x+b)} dx=\frac{\ln^2(a)-\ln^2(b)}{2(a-b)}$$
Is there a way to evaluate this integration?  I really appreciate your interest

This question is similar to: calculate: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x , dx}{(x+a)(x+b)}$ using contour integration. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Let : $$x=\frac{ab}{u}$$ and you're done.
